# G++ can't find boost libraries. I say they're in plain sight

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, boost, g++

I'm trying to build some code. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
main.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0':
/home/jmbeck/Downloads/boost_1_48_0/boost/system/error_code.hpp:214: undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
```

There is more, but I don't think it's relevant.

Here is the build command:

```
g++ -I/home/jmbeck/Downloads/boost_1_48_0 
    -L/home/jmbeck/Downloads/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib 
    -lm 
    -lboost_system 
    -lboost_thread
    -lboost_regex 
    main.cpp
```

The /home/jmbeck/Downloads/boost_1_48_0/stage/lib directory contains the expected files:

```
libboost_system.a
libboost_system.so@
libboost_system.so.1.48.0*
libboost_thread.a
libboost_thread.so@
libboost_thread.so.1.48.0* 
libboost_regex.a
libboost_regex.so@
libboost_regex.so.1.48.0*
... etc...
```

I've tried building a quick program that didn't use the pre-compiled libraries, and it compiled just fine. It finds the appropriate headers, but not the libraries.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can use `-Wall` option to `g++`, and you could use `-v` to understand what it is doing, and `-H` to understand the header files it already found. Your error is a linking error (missing library, or wrong order).

Comment: My actual Makefile does use -Wall and -v (and -Wextra). I wanted to get down to the basics. But that's a good tip for future viewers; it's helped me before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try putting the libraries *after* `main.cpp`.

I've experienced some weirdness in the past when GCC ignores libraries because it doesn't think they're used, before reaching my source files.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I believe I updated gcc at some point in the past. These same Makefiles worked just fine a few months ago. That was frustrating. Thanks again for the tip!

Comment: That should probably be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Often linkers require that libraries be ordered as most dependent to least dependent (I believe MS does not). In this case probably thread or regex depends on system, so you'd need to list the `-lsystem` after the other boost library that depends on it.